# Can I in-game enable blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft modpack with Galacticraft, NEI, Mekanism. (There are actually more mods(75+) but these are important for question) And for some reason, Galacticraft compressor and electric compressor are disabled and not even in NEI. Is here an option to enable them in-game?

Comment: What do you mean by disabled? Are you sure the mod packs are installed correctly?

Comment: Very unlikely. I suspect they're disabled via mod config files, so most likely you will need to dig through them all to find the appropriate entries, modify them and then restart the server.

Comment: They can't by cratfed, they can't be given by NEI, they can be given by command, they are only hidden actually. And they work. You can make  stuff in compressors. I've seen it in another modpack, where it was disabled by some "game balancing" mod. In that modpack, it was disabled only via NEI, which could mean, that they can be enabled somehow in NEI.